# How to change default column widths in Macintosh Finder?

Tags: finder, osx-mavericks, desktop-customization

In Mac OS X Mavericks, I find that when I bring up a finder window showing items in a list with columns, the Name column defaults to being way to wide, I have to scroll to the right to grab column edge and slide it left to see the other columns at the same time as the name such as the date of modification.

How can I get the Finder to provide a more reasonable default column width for all folders?  The solution given by shub appears to only apply to a single folder and would require each new folder navigated to to be set again.

Comment: Try [this](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20030329162110811)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Hold the <kbd>Option</kbd> key while resizing a column
- Close all Finder windows
- When you next open a window, the column will be the same size as you just set!

Note: This will, obviously, only work on 'column' view in Finder :)

Comment: This appears to be folder specific, setting it for one folder and then navigating to another gives the old default really wide first column.  How can this setting be applied to all folders?